# why does scala compile error on if else statement?

Tags: scala, recursion

this is a scala code:

```
def otpu (start : Int, end : Int) : List[Int] = {
  // TODO: Provide definition here.
  if(start<end)
    Nil
  else if(start>end){
     val list0:List[Int] = start::otpu(start-1,end)
     list0
  }
  else if(start==end){
    val list:List[Int] = List(end)
    list  
  }
}
```

It works like `otpu(5,1)=> List(5,4,3,2,1)`

But when I compile, 
I get a compiler error `type mismatch, found: unit,require:List[Int]" at "if(start==end)"`.

When I **delete** `if(start==end)` and there is just `else` **then it works**.

Why does it not work with `if(start==end)`?

Comment: Because then your if is not an expression, but an statement that is doing nothing. Then the compiler inserts a final **Unit** _(`()`)_ at the end of the method, and for that reason you have the error. - PS: Defining a val, just to return it immediately does not look ok, you can just `start :: otpu(start-1,end)` as the body of the if, that way you can even remove the braces.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following.

```
val result = if (conditionA) List(9)
```

This is incomplete. What if `conditionA` is **false**? What is the value of `result` in that case? The compiler resolves this problem by silently competing the statement.

```
val result = if (conditionA) List(9) else ()
```

But now there's a new problem. `()` is of type `Unit`. (It's the *only* value of that type.) Your `otpu` method promises to return a `List[Int]` but the silent `else` clause doesn't do that. Thus the error.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation error is due to the return type mismatch in if,elseif & else condition. As in above code else is missing, therefore the compiler fails to returns the value if & elseif condition are not satisfied.

```
def otpu(start: Int, end: Int): List[Int] = {
// TODO: Provide definition here.
if (start < end)
  Nil
else if (start > end) {
  val list0: List[Int] = start :: otpu(start - 1, end)
  list0
}
else if (start == end) {
  val list: List[Int] = List(end)
  list
}
 else Nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answers you are missing the last `else` condition.
You can get that immediately if you convert the code to use pattern-matching, for instance:

```scala
def otpu (start : Int, end : Int) : List[Int] = {
    start match {
        case `end` => List(end)
        case _ if start > end => start::otpu(start-1, end) 
        case _ => Nil
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I noticed the tag `recursion` in the question and I thought you might want to end up with a recursive function for this. The way you implemented the recursive function is not really safe due to the fact that for a very (very) large list to be produced in output, you might incur in a stack overflow runtime error. To avoid that, Scala gives you the possibility of using tail-recursive functions. Here how it would look like:

```
def otpu(start: Int, end: Int) : List[Int] = {
  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  @tailrec
  def f(e: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    start >= e match {
        // base step
        case false => acc
        // recursive step
        case true => f(e+1, e::acc) 
    }
  }

  // call the recursive function with the empty accumulator
  f(end, Nil)
}
```